# SQL Query on recursive table

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a to do a request on a "recursive table".

Please find below an example

```
ID    |    FATHER_ID    |    NAME
100   |    0            |  Human
101   |    0            |  Car
102   |    101          |  PORSCHE
103   |    101          |  AUDI
104   |    102          |  911
105   |    102          |  MACAN
106   |    103          |  A3
107   |    103          |  A5
...   |    ...          |
```

I would like to get something like

```
PARENT_NAME   |   NAME
PORSCHE       | 911
PORSCHE       | MACAN
AUDI          | A3
AUDI          | A5
...           | ...
```

I'm able to go to the first level with below query :

```
SELECT ID, FATHER_ID, NAME FROM LISTS WHERE FATHER_ID IN (SELECT ID FROM LISTS WHERE NAME = 'Car')


ID   |   FATHER_ID   |    NAME
102  | 101           | PORSCHE  
103  | 101           | AUDI
```

But is it possible to go to the level 2 (car model) by keeping level 1 information (the brand) ?

I able to get information of level 2 with below query. But I'm losing brand name.

```
SELECT ID, FATHER_ID, NAME FROM LISTS WHERE FATHER_ID IN (SELECT ID FROM LISTS WHERE FATHER_ID IN (SELECT ID FROM LISTS WHERE NAME = 'Car'))
```

Thank you in advance

Regards

Comment: If there are only 2 levels to your relationships you can do a self join (join the table to itself) and use alias on the table names to differentiate the 2.

Comment: Thank you very much. I was not aware about this.

Answer (score 2):

Walk the tree building a cumulative  string as you go, then filter the result to keep only the deepest level

```
With FullTree as (
    Select ID, '' as Names, 0 as Level
    From Lists
    Where Father_ID = 0
  Union All
    Select ID, f.Names + ' | ' + c.Name as Names, f.level+1 as Level
    From Lists c inner join FullTree f on c.Father_ID = f.ID
)
Select Names from FullTree 
Where Level = (Select max(Level) From FullTree)
Order by Names
```

If you wish, you can trim the left part of the string to remove the initial vertical bar.

Answer (score 2):

You can walk the tree in reverse, starting at the lowest level.

```
WITH cte AS (
    SELECT l.ID, l.FATHER_ID, l.NAME
    FROM LISTS l
    WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1
        FROM LISTS child
        WHERE child.FATHER_ID = l.ID)

    UNION ALL

    SELECT parent.ID, parent.FATHER_ID, CONCAT(parent.NAME, '|', child.NAME)
    FROM LISTS parent
    JOIN cte child ON child.FATHER_ID = l.ID
)
SELECT l.NAME
FROM cte
WHERE cte.FATHER_ID IS NULL;   -- this line removes intermediate levels
```